# Split a string of strings by 2 delimeters

Tags: javascript

My string looks like

`"<!number|Foo bar> <!number|Foo bar> <!number|foo bar>"`
I have like to split the string by "<" and ">" so that the new array becomes
`["<!number|string>", "<!number|string>" ]`.

I tried str.split('> <'), which gives me 
`["<!numer|string", "!number|string>"]`.

Also I tried using regex to  str.split(/\<> /)
which gives me `["<!number|string> <!number|string>"]`.

How to split it correctly?

Comment: Shouldn't you have three items in the array?

Comment: why don't you split by whitespace ? `yourString.split(" ")`

Comment: `"<!number|string> <!number|string> <!number|string>".split(" ")` ??

Comment: My string looks like "<!1|Foo bar> <!2|Bar Baz> <!3| xxx yyy>", so splitting by space does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At work so I can't fix the nitty gritty with the regex, but the below works given the string

```js
const str = `<!1|Foo bar> <!2|Bar Baz> <!3| xxx yyy>`;
console.log(str.split(/(<[\s\S]*?>)/gm).filter((n)=> { return (n!="" && n!=" ") }));
```

Comment: it worked. Thanks. Also I used /\<\!\d+\|[^>]+\>/ and used match to get matched strings as array!

Answer (score 1):

Just split on `space`:

```js
let str = "<!number|string> <!number|string> <!number|string>";

console.log(str.split(" "));
```